CkEditor issues with request headers
I have an issue with my code when I upgrade my CKeditor from 4.23 to 4.24 LTS. For some odd reason, my upload method in flask is not working anymore and returns none. Below is my code where it fails and returns the error message
@app.route("/up", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def upload_file():
    try:
        fnum = int(request.args.get("CKEditorFuncNum", None)) 
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return "<html><body><script type='text/javascript'>alert('Unknown function');</script></body></html>"

I tried disable the license key check in CKeditor. I also tried hard digging around CKeditor to see what the changes were but it didn't seem to significant.
Edit: Error code is below that shows up in my console. The network tab shows the image as 200 and csrf token as 200
ckeditor.js:379 [CKEDITOR] Error code: filetools-response-error. 
{responseText: "<html><body>\x3Cscript type='text/javascript'>alert('Unknown function');\x3C/script></body></html>"}
responseText
: 
"<html><body><script type='text/javascript'>alert('Unknown function');</script></body></html>"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object


Use the Network tab of DevTools to see what parameters are being sent in the request.

The network tab shows nothing that is of help. My image and csrf token are good! The console does show an error code called filetools-response-error
